# Is this a safe way to check if a property exist else assign one?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Below is an extract from MDN example

```
var d = withValue.d || (
  withValue.d = {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    value: value
  }
);
```

Is this a safe way to check if a property exist else assign and initialize it ? If not is there a better, safe and optimized way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not safe, because the property may indeed exist on the object but be *falsey*, in which case the `withValue.d ||` would fail and go onto the alternation, assigning an object to the `d` property despite the fact that the `d` property already exists. Use `hasOwnProperty` instead, and don't put an assignment where an expression is expected:

```
if (!withValue.hasOwnProperty('d')) {
  withValue.d = {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    value: value
  }
}
const { d } = withValue;
```

If the `d` property, if it exists, *will always be an object*, then your original code will *work*, because objects are always truthy. (Code is still somewhat smelly though, due to the assignment-as-expression)

Comment: Why the last line `const { d } = withValue;`?

Comment: I just prefer destructuring when possible (as do many linters) - less to type, less syntax noise. (Imagine if `d` was long - then, you'd need `const somePropNameHere = withValue.somePropNameHere`) Feel free to use `const d = withValue.d`

Answer (score 0):

### No, you should check if it's `in` the object instead

Just like @certainperformance said, it is not safe to check if a property exists on an object by checking it's value. Instead, you can simply check if the property is `in` the object using [JavaScript's in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
if (!('d' in withValue)) {
  withValue.d = { ... };
}

const { d } = withValue;
```

The only issue you may run into is that `prop in obj` will not just check the properties on an object but also the prototype. However, for most cases that is probably fine.